# Normalize Image Brightness and Saturation

Tags: java, imagemagick

I have a collection of **colored/black-white** images and most of them have different levels of brightness and saturation.

```
How can I normalize those images to make them all at the same "**scale**"?
```

In my case, some of the images might also have a huge amount of **white pixels** as they are the scans of some old photos.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the "`-normalize`" option of ImageMagick?  There are more complex methods that produce better results, but you might like the result as a first cut at fixing them.

Comment: Just to add a little to Glenn's command, a simple approach is just to stretch the histogram. You can use -contrast-stretch 0% to stretch the histogram to full dynamic range or to clip a little off the dark and light ends of the histogram to stretch it even more. This increases contrast/brightness. -normalize is just  -contrast-stretch 2%x1%. See http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#contrast-stretch. Also -auto-level and -auto-gamma combined are effective and simple.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to suggest anything very concrete without seeing your images, but one idea might be to move to a colourspace that is based on Brightness and Saturation and then to do an auto-gamma correction on the two channels of interest.

**It could make a horrible mess so please make backup of your images first!**

So, I am suggesting something along the lines of:

```
convert Original.jpg -colorspace HSL -channel B -auto-gamma -colorspace sRGB BrightnessNormalised.jpg
```

where I move to *"Hue, Saturation and Lightness"* colourspace, select the `Lightness` channel (it is the 3rd one so it is `B` out of `RG&B`) and do an auto-gamma of the `Lightness` and save back as a brightness-corrected, sRGB JPEG.

Likewise, to normalise the saturation, you could do:

```
convert Original.jpg -colorspace HSL -channel G -auto-gamma -colorspace sRGB SaturationNormalised.jpg
```

And you could do both at once, by using `-channel GB` like this:

```
convert Original.jpg -colorspace HSL -channel GB -auto-gamma -colorspace sRGB Normalised.jpg
```

Normalising the saturation is probably not a good idea for greyscale images but do some tests.

Normalising the brightness of images is not really a good idea if you have moody, low-key photographs or airy, light, high-key photographs. Hang onto that backup - just make a ZIP/compressed tar-ball and keep it around.

Comment: Please provide an example or two. Do you want to match image brightnesses or just optimize them. There are many ways to do either. Do you mean saturation or contrast? A little more guidance and examples would go a long way to help point us in the right direction. If you are on a Unix-like system, then you could look a my ImageMagick scripts for many approaches under the categories of either Color or Brightness/Contrast at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.html. For example you can match two images brightness and contrast via scripts histmatch or matchimage. See also autotune

Comment: Continued: Several scripts to look at for general color image optimization are: http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/autotone/index.php (which is based upon -auto-gamma and white/gray balancing), http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/redist/index.php (which is based upon reshaping the histogram), http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/retinex/index.php, http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/space/index.php (which is a spatially adaptive contrast enhancement), http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/enhancelab/index.php (which increases color in LAB space)

Comment: Most of my Images are like this one: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-awVv7mV3lTs/TuqneVP1LSI/AAAAAAAAAGc/cO7X-DGqolM/s1600/RG2.JPG  the majority of it are photos instead of scans, so the quality is not as good as this one. I will try it and then post my results

Comment: In summary, the ideal image would be like http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-awVv7mV3lTs/TuqneVP1LSI/AAAAAAAAAGc/cO7X-DGqolM/s1600/RG2.JPG  the majority of it are photos looks like this one http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-eWN-h8xw3N0/UMZO8b1JhjI/AAAAAAAAR-8/gW_T2hco5C0/s1600/DSCF4207.jpg with many variations of light, I would like to try to make the colors/brightness of second one as close as possible as the first one.