# comparing images with different brightness

Tags: image, opencv

I want to find if two images are the picture of the same art work (below are two pics of a work from japanese artist Yoshitomo Nara)

[image: file1]

[image: file2]

I aligned the two pics using feature match and affine transformation. So the images are now of identical size and supposedly well aligned.

[image]
[image]

but in some cases (e.g. in this one), the two pictures have different brightnesses. 
directly comparing greyscale images doesn't work.

I tried equal hist, which makes the situation even worse
[image]
[image]

I also tried some other methods, including:

number of matches in feature match;

ssim https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_similarity

phash https://www.phash.org/

none of them work very well.

My guess is I need to first get rid of the brightness difference. But I'm not sure how to do it. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: There are a couple of ideas here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/44386554/2836621 and also see Fred's incisive comments beneath.

Comment: You need some preprocessing before using features. I suggest using anisotropic filtering to smooth out the image and enhance the edges.

Comment: I looked at the link Mark provided. the brightness normalized using imagemagick. There is more things to try in Fred's script list, but I'm using windows, so it will take me some time to implement them.

Comment: Burak, I'm not familiar with anisotropic filter. I google it and this seems mainly for computer graphic.

Comment: @YuanRen Please tag someone when you tell something specifically to him to get notifications. I suppose brightness normalization is the same as histogram equalization which you already tried, by the way.
The features between the images should be consistent. The background is not informative in this case, but SIFT or whatever detector you use detects features in background, thus we need to eliminate them. If we diffuse the brightness in those regions while preserving edges, we can obtain the desired image. That is what anisotropic filter does. Try googling "egde preserving filter".

Comment: @burak thanks for telling me about tagging. I read the material on edge preserving filter by W. Burger. This seems a very powerful tool. But I don't see how to use it in my case: the average brightness of two pictures will not be reduced, so pixel-wise comparison is still not feasible; If I just want to compare the edges, I can directly use edge detection, not sure anisotropic filter can help that. By the way, I'm using cv.ximgproc.anisotropicDiffusion, is this the right function?

Comment: @YuanRen I don't think feature detection depends on brightness. I think feature matching fails because there are unwanted variations in flat areas which cause detection of different features. Histogram equalization results show the difference more clearly. Eliminating variations in flat areas would be sufficient for a successful feature matching. You do not need to adjust brightness. I did not use the filter in OpenCV, but it should be the right function.

Comment: @Burak Yes, feature match works well, it's not affected too much by the brightness. But after feature matching and affline transformation, I'm thinking since two images are already well aligned, maybe it's better to use perform some pixel to pixel comparison, so the brightness becomes a big problem.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was giving answers to get structrally similar images from different art works. Also, features work well on matching similar images, but it appears you want to distinguish different art works.

Comment: @burak features work ok in my case too. when there is a large number of good matches between too pictures, usually they are the same painting. But occasionally, artist creates mutliple works which are reorganizations of the same underlying components, e.g. Andy Warhol. So I was thinking in addtional to number of matches, maybe I can add some "simple" pixel level comparison to improve the accuracy. It turns out this is not a trivial thing to do. I guess I will leave with what I have for now, which is usable. Thanks for all the information and discussion, they are very helpful!

Comment: @YuanRen You may want to look for Bag Of Viual Words if you think of training and learning images using extracted features. You are welcome!

Comment: @Burak I saw some articles mentioned this Bag of Visual Words method, it seems pretty powerful. But I'm not sure if can implement it. Do you know any fool proof package for this?

Comment: @YuanRen There is already [an asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30928135/how-to-use-sift-features-for-bag-of-words-in-opencv) about this topic, and this is the [best source I have](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/619039/Bag-of-Features-Descriptor-on-SIFT-Features-with-O). I recommend you to understand [what a feature is](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/df/d54/tutorial_py_features_meaning.html) first. I decided on second thoughts that BOW method would not be applicable in this specific case, because features try to find similarities whereas you want to discriminate images.

Comment: I know probably some pixel wise operation may give better result for 1 image to 1 image comparison. I'm thinking about BoW mainly for initial screening or a quick search. E.g. if I want to find photos of the same art work in N photos. In worse case, N*(N-1)/2 pair wise comparison is needed. If I can use BoW to prebuild an index of the images, hopefully I can find some good candidates in the complexity of O(N) and only run more accurate comparison on this smaller group. For the well known artists, sometime I have more than 1000 pictures.

Comment: Got it. I advise adding more artworks and the outcome of using BOW to the question.